# Postgres concat distinct keys in map

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, jsonb

What combination of jsonb functions in **Postgres 9.6** can be used for aggregating on distinct keys of a map? (Different values for the same key would result in a random value for that key.)

E.g. given this data:

```
WITH tbl(id, j) as (
values
    (1, '{"key1": "val1"}'::jsonb),
    (1, '{"key2": "val2"}'),
    (1, '{"key2": "val2"}'),
    (2, '{"key3": "val3"}')
)
SELECT id, <what aggregate fn?>(data) FROM tbl GROUP BY 1
```

How can we return a result set that is deduplicated and merged like so?

```
id  | j
----|----------------------------------
1   | {"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"}
2   | {"key3": "val3"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `jsonb_object_agg()` on pairs `(key, value)` got from `jsonb_each()` used in a lateral join:

```
with tbl(id, j) as (
values
    (1, '{"key1": "val1"}'::jsonb),
    (1, '{"key2": "val2"}'),
    (1, '{"key2": "val2"}'),
    (2, '{"key3": "val3"}')
)
select id, jsonb_object_agg(key, value)
from tbl 
cross join jsonb_each(j)
group by 1

 id |         jsonb_object_agg         
----+----------------------------------
  1 | {"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"}
  2 | {"key3": "val3"}
(2 rows)
```

---

Update. You can create a custom aggregate:

```
create or replace function jsonb_object_merge(jsonb, jsonb)
returns jsonb language plpgsql as $$
begin
    return jsonb_object_agg(key, value)
    from ( 
        select key, value from jsonb_each($2)
        union   
        select key, value from jsonb_each($1)
    ) s;
end $$;

create aggregate my_jsonb_object_agg(jsonb)
(
    sfunc = jsonb_object_merge,
    stype = jsonb
);
```

which may be useful in more complex queries (together with other aggregates):

```
with tbl(id, j, v) as (
values
    (1, '{"key1": "val1", "key4": "val4"}'::jsonb, 1),
    (1, '{"key2": "val2"}', 1),
    (1, '{"key2": "val3"}', 1),
    (2, '{"key3": "val3"}', 1)
)
select id, my_jsonb_object_agg(j), sum(v)
from tbl
group by 1

 id |               my_jsonb_object_agg                | sum 
----+--------------------------------------------------+-----
  1 | {"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2", "key4": "val4"} |   3
  2 | {"key3": "val3"}                                 |   1
(2 rows)
```

Comment: I see that this unnests to rows, so that if we have more than one key-val pair that would result in duplicate rows. Would you recommend moving this to a CTE/subquery with a JOIN on id in that case?

Comment: Well, this should not lead to duplicate rows. Maybe I do not understand the issue. Could you give an example in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17

Comment: I see, this cannot be aggregated in a single select, I would do it in this way - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/22378